# Allow objects with same id to be draggable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created the following jQuery code to allow for an object to be draggable:

JavaScript:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#drag_item").draggable();
});
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="drag-item">One</div>
<div id="drag-item">Two</div>
<div id="drag-item">Three</div>
```

Only the first `div` with `id` `"drag-item"` is draggable, but the others are not. I want all of them to be draggable. I understand that this can be done by assigning each one a different `id`, but I would rather just declare one `id` that allows all object with that `id` the functionality of draggable. How would I be able to do this?

Comment: You cannot duplicate ID's like that.. ID's should be unique. Use a class selector

Comment: "objects with same id" <- there's your problem.  Also `drag_item` vs `drag-item`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot duplicate ID's like that.. ID's should be unique. Use a class selector

**HTML:**

```
<div class="drag-item">One</div>
<div class="drag-item">Two</div>
<div class="drag-item">Three</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $(".drag-item").draggable(); //Edit: as MrOBrian pointed out
});
```

Comment: everyone that answered initially missed the `_` / `-` problem :)

Comment: @MrOBrian My mind was blown by duplicate id's. Thats my excuse.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(function(){
    $(".drag-item").draggable();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="drag-item">One</div>
<div class="drag-item">Two</div>
<div class="drag-item">Three</div>
```

Use `class` instead of `id`.

It is not valid html to have duplicate `id`'s.

Comment: also needs consistency with `drag_item` or `drag-item`

Answer (score 5):

If you are free to change the HTML, you can use a `class` instead of an `id`.

```js
$(function(){
    $(".drag-item").draggable();
});
```

```html
<div class="drag-item">One</div>
<div class="drag-item">Two</div>
<div class="drag-item">Three</div>
```

If, however, you're not free to change the HTML, you can use the following:

```js
$(function(){
    $("[id=drag-item]").draggable();
});
```

Unlike the `#drag-item`, the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) will return all matching elements, instead of just the first. Keep in mind, though, that having multiple elements with the same `id` means you have [**invalid HTML**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/127180).

Comment: Hehehe, it's so easy to copy-paste typo's. :-P